# Выделение несовпадающих ячеек в строке таблицы

Tags: html, jquery

Имеется [данный код](http://jsfiddle.net/vrLgg47L/2/). При выделении 2-х строк таблицы, необходимо добавить скрипт, который будет выделять красным, все несовпадения между этими двумя строками.

```
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>remark</th>
        <th>status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>235</td>
        <td>add</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>add</td>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>235</td>
        <td>add</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
        var maxAllowed = 2;
        var cnt = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
             $(this).prop("checked", "");
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#myTable tr').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});

#myTable tbody tr:hover {
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

#myTable tbody tr {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.different{
  color:red;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {

    var arr = [];
    $.each($("#myTable tr"), function(index) {
      if(index == 0)
        return true;//избавляемся от заголовков столбцов таблицы (<th>)
      var num_tr = index;
      var str = [];
      $.each($(this).find("td"), function(index) {
        if($(this).find("input:checkbox").length > 0)
           $(this).find("input:checkbox").attr("data-num",num_tr);
           //строчку выше можно пропустить, но тогда нужно будет другой код для вычисления строки при нажатии на checkbox
        if(index == 0)
            return true; //избавляем массив от знаков из ячейки с checkbox
        str.push($(this).text());
        });
        arr.push(str);
    });

    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
        $("#myTable td").removeClass("different");
        if($(this).is(':checked') && $("#myTable input:checked").length > 1 && $("#myTable input:checked").length < 3){
        // делаем проверку на выделение только двух строк. чтобы функционал работал, нужно, чтобы последний нажатый и выделенный checkbox был вторым из выделенных ранее.
        $.each($("#myTable input:checked"), function(index){
        window["str" + index] = $(this).attr("data-num");
      });
      for(var i = 0; i <=3 ; i++){
        if(arr[str0-1][i] != arr[str1-1][i]){
          $("#myTable tr:nth-child("+str0+") td:nth-child("+(i+2)+") ").addClass("different");
          $("#myTable tr:nth-child("+str1+") td:nth-child("+(i+2)+") ").addClass("different");
        }
      }

    }
    });

});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwqbcxju/)**

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вот это Вам подойдет.

В CSS добавить

```
td.diff {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

И JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var maxAllowed = 2;
    cleanHighlight(); // чистим возможно отмеченное ранее
    var cnt = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
      $(this).prop("checked", "");
    } else if (cnt==maxAllowed) { // если отмечено максимум возможного - начнем сравнение
        compareRows();
    }
  });
});

// чистка - убираем все выделения
function cleanHighlight() {
    $('#myTable td.diff').removeClass('diff');
}

function compareRows() {
    // для каждого выбранного чекбокса идем вверх по дереву до tr и берем все siblings (получаем все td этой строки)
    var rOne = $('input:checkbox:checked').eq(0).parentsUntil('tr').siblings();
    var rTwo = $('input:checkbox:checked').eq(1).parentsUntil('tr').siblings();
    // проходим по всем td и сравниваем по одному их содержимое
    for(i=0; i<=rOne.length; i++) {
        if (rOne.eq(i).html()!=rTwo.eq(i).html()) {
            // если содержмиое разное - добавляем CSS класс
            rOne.eq(i).addClass('diff');
            rTwo.eq(i).addClass('diff');
        }
    }
}
```

Однако, учтите, что это будет нормально работать если Вам надо сравнивать 2 строки.
Если строк на сравнение будет больше, то надо будет править...